# Odoo - Error de campo inexistente

Tags: python, mvc, odoo

Estoy haciendo este modelo de peliculas pero a la hora de actualizar los cambios dice que la aprte de clasificaicon no existe o no esta definido y segun esto si esta bien puesto no tnego ningun error de sintaxis que tendria que hacer para poder corregir ese error

Adjunto codigo:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

class Presupuesto(models.Model):
_name = "presupuesto"

name = fields.Char()
clasificacion = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('G', 'G'),
    ('PG', 'PG'),
    ('PG-13', 'PG-13'),
    ('R', 'R'),
    ('NC-17', 'NC-17'),
])
fch_esteno = fields.Date()
puntuacion = fields.Integer()
active = fields.Boolean()
```

al actualizar para ver en el navegador los cambios manda un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pone que la variable id de clasificacion no existe o no esta declarada pero si esta

Comment: Ajusta la identación, ya que en python es importante y el error puede venir deahí en too caso. 
También afrega tu estructura de tu tabla

Comment: la identacion esta bien y esos son todos los atributos de la tabla

Comment: En la pregunta la identación no es correcta, si ejecutas eso dará un error de identación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza el modulo de nuevo desde las aplicaciones. Cuando estas creando nuevos campos, en ocasiones no se actualiza la BD y hay que forzar la actualización.

Comment: esto no debería ser un comentario?

Comment: @Christian - No, es la solución al problema que comenta. Es un problema recurrente en odoo. No es problema de identación por que le daría error diferente.